# Usage of "ever"

Tags: adverbs

Which one is correct:
*This is one of our favorite ever holidays!* or 
*This is one of our favorite holidays ever!*

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The second is correct. The first is ungrammatical. _Ever_ comes at the end of the noun phrase that contains the superlative _favorite_ it intensifies. _This is our favorite ever!_ is fine, but if _favorite_ modifies a noun phrase, then _ever_ has to come after it.

Comment: It’s been a few days now, and there’re no another in coming answer. Trying editing some contexts in your question will make your question active again. And if there was a correct answer for your question, please marked an answer as correct (the green check image) on It.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are informal. If I had to guess, I would say that the second version (ending with *ever*) is the more common of the two.

But there is nothing syntactically wrong with either one.

While acting in an adjectival manner, *ever* is really being used as an *intensifier*. From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-degree/intensifiers-very-at-all):

> Intensifiers are adverbs or adverbial phrases that strengthen the meaning of other expressions and show emphasis.

Some examples are:

> *She was* ***so*** *upset. I felt* ***extremely*** *sorry for her.*
>   *Don’t work* ***too*** *hard. Sometimes you’ll get more done by relaxing a bit*.
>   *She’s* ***really*** *offended her sister.*

The intensifier *ever* is normally used with a question:

> *Why did I* ***ever*** *invite them to stay with us?*

But it can also be used in a declarative, such as with your core sentence:

> This is one of our favorite (ever) holidays (ever)!

In the first case, it emphasizes *favorite*; in the second, either *holidays* or the whole phrase *favorite holidays*.

Probably a more common expression involving it is (in two different variations):

> You're my best friend ever!
>   You're my best ever friend!

Comment: Yes, I would find it more natural to say 'best ever' than 'favourite ever'. It's a shorter way to say 'one of the best holidays I have ever had'.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you need the word **`"ever"`** in this sentence. It doesn't sound right for me.

- Since **`"ever"`** has superlative expression which means *the thing described by* **`"ever"`** *must be* **`the one/thing`** and **`only`** *with the highest quality or degree for individual emotional state.*

> This is one of our favorite holidays.

- "This is one of our . . ." means you have something more than one.
- "Favorite holidays" states holidays that you like are on the same degree of liking or fondness.

---

### So the word **`"ever"`** is not supposed to be used here.

---

Mostly we use **`"ever"`** with superlative clause. You can say something like:

> **Example: This is our most favorite holiday ever!**
>
> > *If you could choose one holiday you enjoyed the most.*
> >
> > > *The word "most" here describes that you like this holiday the most, since you have more than one favorite holiday.*
> >
> > ***[or just . . .](http://#)***
>
> **Example: This is one of our favorite holidays.**
>
> > **Note:** *We don't use "the most favorite" because "favorite" already has superlative expression itself.*

Comment: This is nonsense. Have a look at the example sentences [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ever), such as *That was your best performance ever - congratulations!* or *The company has had one of its best years ever.*